# nunjucks not outputting all data from MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nunjucks

I am using node.js as a scripting language and I am also using nunjucks as the template engine. I have a weird situation going where some of the data that I retrieve from the MongoDB database is not being printed into document.

*As you see hear these are the values that I want to print to the web page*
[image]

*But when you look at the web page, only some of the data has been printed out and  the other information is missing.*
[image]

*I console.logged the data to prove that the values are in the database*
[image]

*A weird thing is that if you write the whole object into the code, like so*
[image]

*It will output all the data in one block. That includes the month, the year, and slug property that I am trying to output to the page. Yet, it only does that if I print out the whole object*
[image]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: In brief. Get rid of the pictures and only include the relevant data and code **"as text"**. An amazing medium that somehow I think is actually used to write your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was the problem. In my mongoose schema, I did not have  the properties listed like slug, month, or date. So when I tried to retrieve data from those properties it did not output them. So If you are having similar problems make sure the properties are declared in your mongoose schema